# Angular 2/Web Api - json parsing error syntax error unexpected end of input

Tags: json, rest, asp.net-web-api, angular

I have a Web API controller that looks like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Test()
    {
        return Ok();
    }
```

This is correct syntax, However when I try to call this from a service in Angular 2, I get the error message: "json parsing error syntax error unexpected end of input." To resolve this issue, I have to put a value into the ActionResult such as

```
return Ok(1)
```

Am I missing some configuration? My Angular 2 service call looks like this:

```
return this.http.post(API/Controller/Test).map(res => res.json());
```

Comment: For a similar problem in HttpClient see this discussion: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18680

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I guess that when you receive an empty response (without payload) you don't need to call the `json` method. Under the hood, the XHR response is undefined, `JSON.parse(undefined)` is called and an error is thrown.

You could skip the call of the `map` operator:

```
return this.http.post(API/Controller/Test)/*.map(res => res.json())*/;
```

Answer (score 47):

Another way:

All my http.get, post or put call (for uniformity):

```
.map(this.extractData)
```

In extractData (UPDATED: thanks to raykrow feedback, short code):

```
private extractData(res: Response) {        
    return res.text() ? res.json() : {}; ;
}
```

Comment: I used this concept to fix the same issue but implemented as `return res.text() ? res.json() : {};`

Comment: same as raykow but as `map(res => res.text() ? res.json() : res)`

Answer (score 7):

Strictly speaking if your API is returning an OK code with no content you should return 204 (no content) - Angular would also be happy with this and not try to parse anything. So your controller method would become:

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Test()
{
    return NoContent();
}
```