# Subscribe to observable when Web API returns void

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api2

I have a web api delete method returning void

In angular 2 if I do not subscribe to an Observable, web api method will never get called. [Question](https://forums.asp.net/t/2084202.aspx?Angular%202%20http%20put%20not%20calling%20Controller) and [Cold vs Hot observables](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/creating.md#cold-vs-hot-observables). Since there is a need to return an observable and subscribe, I am trying to return an Observable as:

Service.ts

```
public deleteProduct = (product: ProductApi): Observable<boolean> | boolean => {
   this._http.delete(this.actionUrl + product.productId)
   .catch((error:boolean) => Observable.throw(false));
   return true;
}
```

Component.ts

```
deleteProduct(product: ProductApi, event: any): void {
   event.stopPropagation();
   this.productApiService
   .deleteProduct(product)
   .subscribe((boolean) => {
   this.products = this.products.filter(p => p !== product);
   if (this.selectedProduct === product) { this.selectedProduct = null; }},
      error => console.log(error),
      () => {
      console.log('ProductApiService:Delete completed');
    });
 }
```

controller.cs

```
// DELETE api/product/5
[HttpDelete("{id}")]
public void Delete(int id)
{
    _productService.DeleteProduct(id);
}
```

or there is a way to return an Observable<'void'>? Or if above approach is correct, how can I solve following errors?

- Build: Parameter 'boolean' implicity has an 'any' type
- Build: Parameter 'error' implicity has an 'any' type
- Build: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'boolean | Observable'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need catch inside delete request?
You can just add error logic to error function on subscribing.

```
public deleteProduct(product: ProductApi): Observable<any> {
   return this._http.delete(this.actionUrl + product.productId);
}
```

And then

```
deleteProduct(product: ProductApi, event: any): void {
   event.stopPropagation();
   this.productApiService
   .deleteProduct(product)
   .subscribe(
     response => {
       this.products = this.products.filter(p => p !== product);
       if (this.selectedProduct === product){
         this.selectedProduct = null; 
       }},
      error => console.log(error),
      () => {
      console.log('ProductApiService:Delete completed');
    });
}
```

And if after this changes your controller  still not called I think it is routing error.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I do not understand well why you are using map function as: .map(response => response.json()); since WebAPI does not return any value just void?

Comment: Here is explanation for which response web api converts void return type: https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/action-results.

Accordingly to this source the response will looks like:
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
Date: Mon, 27 Jan 2014 02:13:26 GMT

Comment: Yes, your code not used any response data so you can delete this line of code.This response may be useful to check response status code and implement different logic for different status codes.

Comment: Thanks for you help, I found that map(response => response.json()); generates a json parsing error syntax error unexpected end of input. Commenting out map as per following question solve the problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35734411/angular-2-web-api-json-parsing-error-syntax-error-unexpected-end-of-input

Comment: I will marked the answer since you clarify the mapping issue. Thank you